# Flask request ends up in 500 server error on Azure

Tags: python, azure, flask

I have a Flask web app running on Azure, I started coding the app and everything worked perfectly until I decided to make a request to fetch some info from the YouTube API.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
from flask_restful import Resource

class GetChannelList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        url = "https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyDHYcHfhnhIiuQUejcfkeorMHNQDL4Htvc&channelId=UCvS6-K6Ydmb4gH-kim3AmjA&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20"
        return requests.get(url).content.json()
```

Then on another Python file I have:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from api.get_channel_list import GetChannelList
app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(GetChannelList, "/api/get_channel_list")

import FlaskWebProject1.views
```

And finally, on my Angular controller I have this:

```
$scope.GetChannelList = function(){
            $http.get('api/get_channel_list').then(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
            });
            return $scope.data;
        }
```

Everything was working fine until the app does the request to YouTube, then the following message appears:

[image: azure error]

So I decided to check logs and this is what appears on them:

[image: azure error 2]
[image: azure error 3]

I just started this Friday working with Flask and Azure, and I have no idea what to do next to fix this. Any help or indication as to what may fix this would be appreciated.

Here's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Generated web.config for Microsoft Azure. Remove this comment to prevent
     modifications being overwritten when publishing the project.
-->
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER" value="FlaskWebProject1.app" />
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_ACTIVATE_THIS" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\activate_this.py" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.get_virtualenv_handler()" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Python27\python.exe|D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="^/FlaskWebProject1/static/.*" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**

The following errors are produced:

> SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI
> (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this
> platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS
> certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a
> newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see
> https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>
> InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
> This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
> certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
> Python to solve this. For more information, see
> https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>
> InsecurePlatformWarning
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='content.googleapis.com', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url:
> /youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyCxd3KGNNiZy-omyDH7U8Lr3zGQD6ZO448&channelId=UCvS6-K6Ydmb4gH-kim3AmjA&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:14090086:SSL
> routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed'),))

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Azure or Flask, but does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200782/azure-flask-http-error-500-0-internal-server-error

Comment: I did take a look at his problem, but it had to do something with the fact he was using flask's session manager to handle authentication, which is not my case.

Comment: It must be `requests.get(url).content.json()` cause the exception. The `content` of response is `bytes`. If you want to get json format of response, Just use `requests.get(url).json()`.

Comment: @stamaimer this works! However, it still throws internal server error on azure (works locally only).

Comment: You mean `requests.get(url).content.json()` doesn't throw a exception in your local machine?

Comment: Yes! It no longer does, it brings the info I need and I can print it on angularJS thus finishing my exercise, however when I deploy it to azure, I keep getting 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1):

As your link for [`SSL Warning`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings) said as below,

> **SNIMissingWarning**
>
> This happens on Python 2 versions older than **2.7.9**. These older versions lack SNI support. This can cause servers to present a certificate that the client thinks is invalid. Follow the pyOpenSSL guide to resolve this warning.

I checked the Python2 version of Azure WebApps via command `python -V` on Kudu console, which is `Python 2.7.8`. So you can try to install a higher version of Python2 via Kudu site extensions (`https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions/#gallery`) as the figure below, such as `Python 2.7.12 x86`.

[image]

Then, it will be installed at the path `D:\home\Python27\`, and you need to update the related configuration for Python in the `web.config` file to try  your flask app again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: another question, x86 is the default architecture installed right?

Comment: @codeninja Sure, it's default, unless you enabled the `64-bit` platform option in the application settings tab.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has to do with Azure.

I think that the problem is that your request to YouTube is raising an exception.

`Try/Catch` that block and find out what exception is:

```
class GetChannelList(Resource):
def get(self):
    try:
        url = "https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyDHYcHfhnhIiuQUejcfkeorMHNQDL4Htvc&channelId=UCvS6-K6Ydmb4gH-kim3AmjA&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20"
        return requests.get(url).content.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        return {'message': 'Something went wrong'}
```

To know exactly what went wrong, read the [youtube data api error documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors), and catch them as you like.

**UPDATE**:

Looks like you are using Python 2 which by default comes with `ssl` module that does not support SNI. You have two options. First, upgrade python to Python 3. Or install the security version of requests:

```
pip install 'requests[security]'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: the return of the exception in the form of json wouldn't tell me exactly what went wrong would it?

Comment: should be there, at the very end, by the way, this are the local errors shown, I would assume they're the same on azure @Jahongir Rahmonov

Comment: thanks, trying to implement it, will let you know what changes, thanks!

Comment: Also, I tried to do an $http.get() from that same youtube url on angular and it works fine, the problem is in python, and I've been busting my head for 2 days straight now so I can solve this problem and I haven't found a solution. You have any other idea what I can do to fix this?